# Suppose the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches $z_0$, exists and call it $w_0$. Suppose a sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $z_0$. Does $f(a_n)$ converge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches $z_0$, exists and call it $w_0$. Suppose a sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $z_0$. Does $f(a_n)$ converge to $w_0$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I would say yes but I don't know how to show that $f(a_n)$ goes to $w_0$. The range could be totally different.

My logical proof, Suppose $f(a_n)$ diverges, then since $a_n$ converges to $z_0$ we have that the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches $z_0$ not existing. This contradicts that the limit of $f(z_0)=w_0$, therefore $f(a_n)$ converges. Can you logically follow with this 2 sentence proof?

Comment: What does it mean that $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} f(z) = w_0$? And what does it mean that $a_n \to z_0$? If you look at the definitions, your proof is almost complete.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N$ such that $n>N |f(a_n)-w_0| < \epsilon$ so what does that tell me I am gonna have a limit inside another limit?

Comment: Yes in general $lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(x)=w_0$ (with epsilon delta definiton) iff for every sequence $a_n\rightarrow z_0$ that $f(a_n)\rightarrow w_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=w_0$ (with epsilon delta definiton). This means that for $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$ then $|f(z)-w_0|<\epsilon$.

With this let $a_n$ be a sequence $a_n\rightarrow z_0$ this meanse $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-z_0|<\delta$. This means that $|f(a_n)-w_0|<\epsilon$. Thus $f(a_n)\rightarrow w_0$.

Comment: Wow man that is clear as day!!!!!!!! Is there anything wrong with my little proof?

Comment: drawing a picture makes it really clear also. thats how i understood it

Comment: what would ur picture look like

Comment: First you have this delta window around the point $z_0$, now if we have infinitly many $a_i$'s in this window we should be good. Recall that by definition of sequential limit it implies that for some $N$ that for $n\geq N$ we have $a_{n}\in[z_0-\delta,z_0+\delta]$ (ie in a delta window around $z_0$)

Comment: Actually this proof fails what if $a_n -z_0$ is zero. We are missing that part... we jumped the gun here and we didn't show that was greater than zero

Comment: Yes you are correct. For some reason j just assumed that this wasnt the case. Cause we could have a sequence that just ewuals $z_0$ after some point

Comment: So what would be a counter example? How can we disprove this lie we proved heh

Comment: Look at $ f (x)=1$ everywhere except at $ x=1$ $ f (x)=0$. Look at limit as $ x $ approaches 1. We see limit is equal to 1 but what about sequence $a_n=\{1,1,1,1,...\}$ this sequence converges to 1 but $ f(a_n)=\{0,0,0,0,0,...\}$ thus this converges to 0

Comment: I actually had the same idea so take $ a_n$ to be a infinite sequence of $ z_0$ right?

Comment: Yea pretty much this is an example of hat you said about $a_n-z_0$ being equal to 0

Comment: Was randomly looking back at this and noticed if you add assumption that f s continuous